# iOS set statusbar white, and hide in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need a white status bar for my main initial ViewController, but also be able to hide it in another ViewController. I can do one or the other, but not both at the same time. Any suggestions?

I set it to white by setting

> View controller-based status bar appearance key to NO in the
>   Info.plist

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
}
```

---

And to hide it (on another ViewController presented modally) I do,

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

**however it won't hide unless** I remove the key I previously added to the Info.plist, but if I remove the key, then the status bar goes back to black.

---

EDIT-MY Solution:
The View controller classes were not working in my case because I have the main view controller embedded in a navigation controller, my fix was to override the same methods but for the navigation controller instead of the view controller in question.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    public override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you working on ? i mean swift3 or earlier version ?

Comment: swift 2.2, xcode 7.3... and also need to stay in xcode7.3 for a while.

Comment: Do _not_ use the Info.plist for this. Use the view controller methods provided.

Comment: not on computer anymore (replying from phone) but, if i remove the key from .plist then the status bar remains black, and i need it white.

Comment: I found out my problem, the view controller classes were not working because I have the VC embedded in a NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

If you add

> View controller-based status bar appearance key to NO in the  Info.plist

You should use `[UIApplication setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:]` and `[UIApplication setStatusBarStyle:animated:]`  to change to the statusbar's appearance. Your method won't be called

As it is said in apple's [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10):

> UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance (Boolean - iOS) Specifies whether the status bar appearance is based on the style preferred by the view controller that is currently under the status bar. When this key is not present or its value is set to YES, the view controller determines the status bar style. When the key is set to NO, view controllers (or the app) must each set the status bar style explicitly using the UIApplication object.

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key is the same as `View controller-based status bar appearance` key.

If you don't add the key,your method should work. try add both methods in these two Viewcontrollers, and add some breakpoint to see they're called or override by mistake.

The code in Swift 3.0 Xcode 8.2 works for me:

```
override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
   return .lightContent
}    


override open var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
   return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unable to try right now, will probably try tonight (also, it wasn't me the one that down voted your answer). The thing is that if i remove the key from plist the status bar remains black. Also im running on xcode 7.3 and [UIApplication setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:] is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, like i said i wasn't the one that down voted your answer.  Also I found out my problem, the view controller classes were not working because I have the VC embedded in a NavigationController.